# Adding facebook manychat widget affects Pagepeed insights score

Tags: facebook, magento, magento2, pagespeed-insights, manychats

When I add the Facebook manychat widget on the website, it drops the pagespeed insights score. The reason is widget loads 7-8 different facebook libraries. Is there any solution so it does not affect the score?

Comment: I am afraid the answer is don't use it - you can't control third party code being bloated so either put up with it or use something else. The only thing you could do to make "perceived performance" better is initialise the plugin / add the files with a `setTimeout` - but this doesn't solve the problem it just moves it later (which could improve the Time To Interactive though and improve customer experience)

Answer (score -1):

Add async to your script tag. You can learn more here:
https://javascript.info/script-async-defer